# Why is it enough to look at pullbacks to a closed disk to see if something is a universal quasifibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, pullback

While looking for information about quasifibrations I stumbled over a E-Mail of Tom Goodwillie ([https://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg516.txt](https://www.lehigh.edu/%7Edmd1/tg516.txt)) where he introduces different definitions of quasifibrations and some Lemmas corresponding to that. He defines the notion of being a universal quasifibration so that it should fulfil that every pullback of a weak equivalence along a universal quasifibration is a weak equivalence.
*Definition UQF: A map $p$ is a universal quasifibration (UQF) if $p$ itself and every pullback of this map is a quasifibration.*
Then he gives an easier way to check if something is a UQF.

The original text:
*Lemma 2: If p becomes QF under every base change to a closed
disk, then p is UQF.*

*[Remark: A map to a contractible space is QF iff the inclusion of each
fiber into the total space is a weak equivalence.]*

*Proof (easy, sketched): We have only to show that p is QF. This means
showing that certain extension/lifting
problems w.r.t p have solutions. Every such problem really "lives" over some
disk that's mapped to B, so it's enough if we can solve it after pulling back
to the disk.*

I do understand that the remark is true and I also understand why it is enough to show that $p$ is a quasifibration but I do not know how to do that. Especially I do not know how being a quasifibration is connected to extension/lifting problems w.r.t. $p$.

Comment: Look at $\S2.7$ of the book *Cubical Homotopy Theory* by Munson and Volic.

Comment: Thank you for the reference I was not aware that book existed it seems really helpful.